# How to understand the self-attention mask implementation in google transformer tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model, self-attention

I am reading [google's transformer tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer), and the part why the `attention_mask` for multi-head attention can be built via `mask1 & mask2` was unclear to me. Any help would be great!

```
  def call(self, x, training, mask):

    # A boolean mask.
    if mask is not None:
      mask1 = mask[:, :, None]
      mask2 = mask[:, None, :]
      attention_mask = mask1 & mask2          # <= here 
    else:
      attention_mask = None

    # Multi-head self-attention output (`tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention `).
    attn_output = self.mha(
        query=x,  # Query Q tensor.
        value=x,  # Value V tensor.
        key=x,  # Key K tensor.
        attention_mask=attention_mask, # A boolean mask that prevents attention to certain positions.
        training=training, # A boolean indicating whether the layer should behave in training mode.
        )
```

toy example breakdown

```
input = tf.constant([
    [[1, 0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0]]
])

mask = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(2,2, mask_zero=True).compute_mask(input)
print(mask)
mask1 = mask[:, :, None]   # same as tf.expand_dims(mask, axis = 2)
print(mask1)
mask2 = mask[:, None, :]
print(mask2)

print(mask1 & mask2)

>

tf.Tensor(
[[[ True False  True False]
  [ True  True False False]]], shape=(1, 2, 4), dtype=bool)

tf.Tensor(
[[[[ True False  True False]]

  [[ True  True False False]]]], shape=(1, 2, 1, 4), dtype=bool)

tf.Tensor(
[[[[ True False  True False]
   [ True  True False False]]]], shape=(1, 1, 2, 4), dtype=bool)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 4), dtype=bool, numpy=               # <= why built mask like this?
array([[[[ True, False,  True, False],
         [ True, False, False, False]],

        [[ True, False, False, False],
         [ True,  True, False, False]]]])>
```

Comment: It is impossible for us to know how you are confused without you specifically telling us. You haven't asked a question.

Comment: I have the same question. Can't understand how the if-else part for mask is related to the Transformer encoder input's padding mask definition, especially,  what is this doing: `mask1 = mask[:, :, None]
      mask2 = mask[:, None, :]
      attention_mask = mask1 & mask2`

Answer (score 3):

The following is my understanding. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I think the key to understand the computation of attention mask is **the difference between the attention_mask for multi-head attention and the embedding mask generated by the embedding layer**.

`tf.keras.layers.Embedding` is a mask-generating layer.

With input shape of (batch_size, input_length), `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` generates the embedding mask with the same shape (batch_size, input_length), (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding#input-shape);

`tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` is mask-consuming layer.

When the output tensor of `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` is passed to `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention`, the embedding mask also need to be passed to the latter layer. But `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` requires "attention_mask", which is different to the embedding mask. "attention_mask" is a boolean mask of shape (B, T, S) (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention#call-arguments_1). B for batch_size, T for Target or Query, S for Source or Key.

To compute the attention mask for self attention, we basically need to do an outer product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). This means, for a row token sequence $X$, we need to do $X^T X$. The outcome is the attention matrix where each element is the attention from one word to another. The attention mask would appear in the form of the matrix with the same shape.

The `&` operator in `mask1 & mask2` is [`tf.math.logical_and`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/logical_and).

### A basic example to understand the attention mask in tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention

```
sequence_a = "This is a very long sequence"
sequence_b = "This is short"

text = (sequence_a + ' ' + sequence_b).split(' ')

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(text)
print(le.classes_)

['This' 'a' 'is' 'long' 'sequence' 'short' 'very']

_tokens_a = le.transform(sequence_a.split(' ')) + 1 # 1-based
# print(_tokens_a)
_tokens_b = le.transform(sequence_b.split(' ')) + 1
# print(_tokens_b)

pad_b = tf.constant([[0,_tokens_a.size - _tokens_b.size]])
tokens_b = tf.pad(_tokens_b, pad_b)
tokens_a = tf.constant(_tokens_a)
print(tokens_a)

tf.Tensor([1 3 2 7 4 5], shape=(6,), dtype=int64)

print(tokens_b)

tf.Tensor([1 3 6 0 0 0], shape=(6,), dtype=int64)

padded_batch = tf.concat([tokens_a[None,:], tokens_b[None,:]], axis=0)
padded_batch  # Shape `(batch_size, input_seq_len)`.
```

Tokenization result:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 5],
       [1, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0]])>
```

Embedding mask and attention mask:

```
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10, 4, mask_zero=True)
embedding_batch = embedding(padded_batch)
embedding_batch


<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.0395105 ,  0.02781621, -0.02362361,  0.01861998],
        [ 0.02881015,  0.03395045, -0.0079098 , -0.002824  ],
        [ 0.02268535, -0.02632991,  0.03217204, -0.03376112],
        [ 0.04794324,  0.01584867,  0.02413819,  0.01202248],
        [-0.03509659,  0.04907972, -0.00174795, -0.01215838],
        [-0.03295932,  0.02424154, -0.04788723, -0.03202241]],

       [[-0.0395105 ,  0.02781621, -0.02362361,  0.01861998],
        [ 0.02881015,  0.03395045, -0.0079098 , -0.002824  ],
        [-0.02425164, -0.04932282,  0.0186419 , -0.01743554],
        [-0.00052293,  0.01411307, -0.01286217,  0.00627784],
        [-0.00052293,  0.01411307, -0.01286217,  0.00627784],
        [-0.00052293,  0.01411307, -0.01286217,  0.00627784]]],
      dtype=float32)>



embedding_mask = embedding_batch._keras_mask  # embedding.compute_mask(padded_batch)
embedding_mask

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False]])>




#This is self attention, thus Q and K are the same
my_mask1 = embedding_mask[:, :, None]  # eq: td[:,:,tf.newaxis]
my_mask1

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6, 1), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[[ True],
        [ True],
        [ True],
        [ True],
        [ True],
        [ True]],

       [[ True],
        [ True],
        [ True],
        [False],
        [False],
        [False]]])>

#This is self attention, thus Q and K are the same
my_mask2 = embedding_mask[:, None, :]
my_mask2

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 1, 6), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True, False, False, False]]])>

#According to the `attention_mask` argument of `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention#call-arguments_1), this is the attention_mask which is a boolean mask of shape (B, T, S)
my_attention_mask = my_mask1 & my_mask2
my_attention_mask  #[batch_size, input_seq_len, input_seq_len]

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6, 6), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False]]])>
```